# Difference between EQ Audio Units

Tags: objective-c, macos, audio, signal-processing, core-audio

I'm just starting out with the Audio Units. Currently I'm making an equalizer but I noticed that there are 3 different Audio Units : `AUGraphicEQ`,`AUNBandEQ` and `AUParametricEQ`.I tried to puzzle through the header files but it provides little explanation on the audio units itself and what it provides.

- **What is the difference between them from a programing standpoint in terms of their ease of use and features?**
- **When to choose one over another?**
- **Can I use a combination of them at once?**